# Identifying a succulent and trying to propagate it

Tags: succulents

There are many succulent pictures online, but quite a few match this one we have had for some time.  over the last week or two it shot out the pictured shoots with flowers.  So I'm wondering, would it be possible to snip one of those shoots, and put it in water.  Would it grow?  Also, if so, how long should the shoots be? Thank you!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEJDO.jpg)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's a Mexican snowball a.k.a. *Echeveria elegans*. Nice flowers!

They propagate easily, just take a leaf and put it in dry soil. Give it bright light (but not direct sunlight). After a few weeks it will get roots and you can start watering it and giving it direct sunlight.